# Msys can not find statfs()

Tags: msys

I'm building OpenMPI library on Windows using Msys. But when I try to run the command

```
./configure
```

from the appropriate directory I get lots of output notifying me all files are being checked followed by the next two lines:

> configure: WARNINGS: neither statfs() and statvfs() were found
>
> error: Cannot continue

How can I fix this error?

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/mailman/msys2-users/thread/CAPsJ1NYOZsA7Ge8kj4G%2BNy1X6x7mYyhErDHfKqWfcCQh6DAB%3Dw%40mail.gmail.com/