# Openmpi configure: Could not determine the fortran compiler flag

Tags: configure, openmpi, msys2

I am using Msys2 from PortableApps under Win10. More precisely,

```
$ uname -a
MSYS_NT-10.0-WOW Galapagos 2.11.1(0.329/5/3) 2018-09-10 13:25 i686 Msys
```

I mean to install openmpi. Since I found no pre-built package (I would love to have it!), I downloaded openmpi-3.1.2.
When I

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr/local
```

after many config detections, I get

```
checking for Fortran compiler module include flag...
configure: WARNING: *** Could not determine the fortran compiler flag to indicate where modules reside
configure: error: *** Cannot continue
```

**What is the problem and how can I solve it?**

I found no info on this at all..

Comment: If you do not need Fortran, then `configure --disable-mpi-fortran ...`, otherwise open an issue at https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi and provide the requested info.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet - Did that. Now I have this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47753406/msys-can-not-find-statfs

Comment: are you trying to build Open MPI on native windows ? or via Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) ? If native windows, then Open MPI is not supported on this platform.

Comment: It is Msys2. I wouldn't know how to categorize it for this purpose.